# USB ports do not wake up from suspend to RAM

Tags: linux, usb, power-management, suspend

I have an AMD Athlon 5350 (desktop, not a notebook) and recently upgraded from openSUSE 13.2 to Tumbleweed (openSUSE's rolling release). After that I gave suspend to RAM another try after it had just crashed my system when I last tried with 13.2.

To my surprise it mostly works now. But my mouse (very simple Logitech model) does not wake up. Disconnecting and reconnecting makes it blaze for a very short moment, then it turns dark again. The same result in the neighbour USB port. The funny part: In a third port it did work again. Until the next suspend after which it did not work on four ports (I assume that is two busses). This is not a mouse problem but a port problem: My ventilator which just takes electricity from the port still works but the system does not recognize real USB devices any more.

I currently avoid the problem by starting suspend with the keyboard and disconnectiong the mouse immediately before... But there has to be a better solution. I don't have a notebook thus I am not familiar with this power management stuff and its problems. But I assume that the kernel stores information about the device state somewhere in `/sys/` which may be changed manually.

I cannot say for sure whether `lsusb` still shows all the USB busses (hubs).

**dmesg output**

Messages which may be related to the problem:

When the system suspends, these lines appear:

```
PM: suspend of devices complete after 795.355 msecs
PM: late suspend of devices complete after 1.376 msecs
pcieport 0000:00:02.4: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
r8169 0000:02:00.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 14.713 msecs
ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
```

When it wakes up, these line appear:

```
ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
pcieport 0000:00:02.4: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 13.259 msecs
PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.378 msecs
```

Comment: Any relevant message in dmesg ?

Comment: @SHW Connecting devices to the affected ports does not create messages in `dmesg`.

Comment: While waking up, kernel prints few messages. Did you find any clue in those messages ?

Comment: @SHW I found some lines and added them to the question.

Comment: Checkout [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/813298/349837).

Answer (score 4):

Use the following parameter as kernel option (in grub2):

```
usbcore.autosuspend=-1
```

After using this, you will find:

```
cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
-1
```

The default value is 2. The kernel parameter changes this value.

Setting the kernel parameter helped me. Now my mice works again, when resuming from suspend.

Suggestion:
When USB devices don't work after suspend, you can also reload the driver using the following commands as root:

```
modprobe -r uhci_hcd
modprobe uhci_hcd
```

and / or

```
modprobe -r ehci_hcd
modprobe ehci_hcd
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But `cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend` was already -1 for me. And the other commands have errors such as "FATAL: Module uhci_hcd is builtin." I'm on 20.04 https://askubuntu.com/q/1358360/48214

Comment: After putting this into /etc/default/grub I got "usbcore.autosuspend=-1: not found" from update-grub.