# How to fix no USB power after suspend on Manjaro?

Tags: usb, manjaro, power-management, suspend, hibernate

After suspend and resuming, my USB aren't powered anymore and it won't disover the devices on my Tinkpad E14. (I have a hub on which my PC and mouse are plugged in.) On reboot, everthing works fine but I want to be able to suspend my system and continue working on it.

I assume there is a bug in the power management. I haven't configured anything special but the default rules should apply:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb[0-9]/power/control                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
auto
auto
auto
auto
```

Reading about it, I found this script that is supposed to rebind the USB ports but for me it had no effect:

```
#!/bin/bash
#reset all USB1/2/3 ports
for i in /sys/bus/pci/drivers/[uoex]hci_hcd/*:*; do
  [ -e "$i" ] || continue
  echo "${i##*/}" > "${i%/*}/unbind"
  echo "${i##*/}" > "${i%/*}/bind"
done
```

What sometimes works is unplugging the USB cable and use a different port, yet I also don't want that as a longtime solution.

How can I reset my USB ports on resume after suspend / hibernate on Manjaro?

Comment: Do the solutions in https://askubuntu.com/q/1044988/1078456 help?

Comment: @LjmDullaart I tried with `modprobe ehci_hcd`, haven't tried the `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` approach in grub yet.

Comment: Related maybe duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260907/usb-ports-do-not-wake-up-from-suspend-to-ram/342953#342953